# Substitute symbol for text in table cells and maintain center alignment

Tags: css, html-table, accessibility, substitution

I've got a table showing participation of countries in a project in 2013 and 2018. For a year in which a country participated, we want to display a black circle. The cell will be empty for a year in which the country didn't participate.

For the sake of accessibility, I was figuring on having "Yes" and "No" in the table, and then using CSS repositioning and the ::before pseudo-element to put the screen reader-readable text off-screen and swap the black circle into place in the Yes cells.

I could tell that the black circle wasn't centered. To emphasize what was going on, I replaced "Yes" with "Affirmative" and replaced "No" with a hollow circle instead of nothing. The display produced by the code below shows that the circles are being displayed at the left of where the words "Affirmative" and "No" would have been if I hadn't displaced them. How can I display the symbols centered in the columns instead?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: none;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

/* thead */
table thead th {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

table thead th.text {
    text-align: left;
}

table thead th.indicator {
    text-align: center;
}

table thead th:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

/* tbody */
table tbody th,
table tbody td {
    padding: 0.15em 1em;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

table tbody th {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

table tbody td {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

table tbody td.text {
    text-align: left;
}

table tbody td.indicator {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Specifics for IC tables */
table.ic thead th {
    color: white;
    background-color: #6BB1C9;
}

table.ic tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th,
table.ic tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #E1F0F4;
}


/* Indicator symbol substitution */
table tbody td .yes {
    position: relative;
    left: -999em;
    width: 0;
}

table tbody td .yes::before {
    position: relative;
    left: 999em;
    content: "\0025cf";
}

table tbody td .no {
    position: relative;
    left: -999em;
    width: 0;
}

table tbody td .no::before {
    position: relative;
    left: 999em;
    content: "\0025cb";
}
</style>

<h1>Table example</h1>
<table class="ic">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Country</th><th scope="col" class="indicator">2013</th><th scope="col" class="indicator">2018</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Australia</th>  <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="no">No</span>    </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Bolivia</th>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Croatia</th>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="no">No</span>    </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Denmark</th>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Ethiopia</th>   <td class="indicator"><span class="no">No</span>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">France</th> <td class="indicator"><span class="no">No</span>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Germany</th>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

This gives me:

[image: Web table display]

Without the substitution, I get the following, which shows that the symbols are being positioned at the left edge of where the words would be if I hadn't displaced them.

[image]

Can anyone give me any tips? I've tried setting widths of the displaced text to 0 and hiding overflow, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this approach (if you care about accessibility) is that CSS pseudo-elements aren't actually added to the DOM. Most browsers will compensate for this, but [Internet Explorer doesn't](https://tink.uk/accessibility-support-for-css-generated-content/). There are enough people using IE that this matters. Resizing content to zero pixels height or width will also prevent screen readers from announcing the content.

A better way of approaching this issue would be to load all content into the DOM and then use the `aria-hidden` attribute on the content you DON'T want screen readers to announce.

Here's a fiddle of a more accessible version of this:
https://jsfiddle.net/2jvL6f0L/

Comment: Accessibility is why I'm following this approach. The actual semantic content ("Yes", "No") for the screen reader is in the original HTML document, and is therefore in the DOM from the outset. It's the translation of those words off the screen via CSS and the bullets being added by means of the ::before pseudo-element that are the visual candy.

Comment: The use of `width: 0;` on the `yes` and `no` classes are still a problem. Do not size content to 0 pixels if you want the content to be read by a screen reader. https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#techniques

Comment: OK, I see, thanks. Fortunately, I've come up with another solution, though, that doesn't involve setting any widths or hiding anything, and that takes advantage of the calc() feature that Abid Raza brought to my attention in his response.

Answer (score 1):

No need to hide span by positioning it to -999em.
See the following solution. Hope this will help. ([JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/q5f61dce/2/))

Here I've just made the span text transparent and positioned :before by calc(). This will always make it aligned in the middle.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: none;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

/* thead */
table thead th {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

table thead th.text {
    text-align: left;
}

table thead th.indicator {
    text-align: center;
}

table thead th:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

/* tbody */
table tbody th,
table tbody td {
    padding: 0.15em 1em;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

table tbody th {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

table tbody td {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

table tbody td.text {
    text-align: left;
}

table tbody td.indicator {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Specifics for IC tables */
table.ic thead th {
    color: white;
    background-color: #6BB1C9;
}

table.ic tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th,
table.ic tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #E1F0F4;
}


/* Indicator symbol substitution */
table tbody td .yes {
    position: relative;    
    width: 100%;
    color: transparent;
    display: block;
}

table tbody td .yes::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    content: "\0025cf";
    display: block;    
    color: #000;
    width: 20px;    
}

table tbody td .no {
    position: relative;    
    width: 100%;
    color: transparent;
    display: block;
}

table tbody td .no::before {    
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    content: "\0025cb";
    display: block;    
    color: #000;
    width: 20px;    
}
```

```html
<h1>Table example</h1>
<table class="ic">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Country</th><th scope="col" class="indicator">2013</th><th scope="col" class="indicator">2018</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Australia</th>  <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="no">No</span>    </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Bolivia</th>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Croatia</th>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="no">No</span>    </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Denmark</th>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Ethiopia</th>   <td class="indicator"><span class="no">No</span>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">France</th> <td class="indicator"><span class="no">No</span>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
    <tr>    <th scope="row">Germany</th>    <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  <td class="indicator"><span class="yes">Affirmative</span>  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm content with the off-the-screen approach, but setting the alignment on those cells to left and then setting, for the ::before content, left: calc(50% + 998.75em) did the trick for me! So thanks for bringing calc() to my attention.

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with *one* solution: set `display: block;` on the ::before. That has a couple of side effects: the table rows are now taller than I'd like, even though I've set padding and margin to 0; and the circles aren't *vertically* centered, and setting `vertical-align: middle;` doesn't fix that. I've wound up setting `top: 4px;` but I'm not thrilled with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating ideas from previous responses here, I've now come up with the following replacement for my previous approach.

```
table tbody td.indicator {
    text-align: left; /* not center */
}

...

table tbody td .yes {
    position: relative;
    left: -999em;
}

table tbody td .yes::before {
    position: relative;
    left: calc(50% + 998.75em);
    content: "\0025cf";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one solution that should help.

I moved the `Affirmative` and `No` into the `title` attribute of the `<span>` and placed the HTML elements for the two kinds of circles as the content of the `<span>`

This removed the need for the `:before` in the CSS.

The title helps with Accessibility, but not really since all the screen readers will read is the word "Affirmative" or "No" with no context. It might be better, if you are concerned about screen readers to improve on the `title` attribute to be something more like: `title="Affirmative for Germany in 2013"` or something like that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: none;
    margin: 1em 0;
  }

  /* thead */
  table thead th {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 1em;
  }

  table thead th.text {
    text-align: left;
  }

  table thead th.indicator {
    text-align: center;
  }

  table thead th:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
  }

  /* tbody */
  table tbody th,
  table tbody td {
    padding: 0.15em 1em;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
  }

  table tbody th {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  table tbody td {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
  }

  table tbody td.text {
    text-align: left;
  }

  table tbody td.indicator {
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* Specifics for IC tables */
  table.ic thead th {
    color: white;
    background-color: #6BB1C9;
  }

  table.ic tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th,
  table.ic tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #E1F0F4;
  }
  </style>
</html>
<body>
<h1>Table example</h1>
  <table class="ic">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col" class="indicator">2013</th>
        <th scope="col" class="indicator">2018</th>
      </tr>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Australia</th>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="No">&#x25CB;</span></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bolivia</th>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Croatia</th>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="No">&#x25CB;</span></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Denmark</th>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Ethiopia</th>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="No">&#x25CB;</span></td>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">France</th>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="No">&#x25CB;</span></td>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Germany</th>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        <td class="indicator"><span title="Affirmative">&#x25CF;</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```